# Sorting 'Index' array

Tags: java

Can anybody tell what is the best(easy) way to sort the following string 'index' array in java

```
String [] menuIndex= { "0",
                       "1",
                       "2",
                       "3",
                       "0.0",
                       "0.0.1",
                       "0.0.0",
                       "0.0.4",
                       "14" ,
                       "14.0",
                       "0.1"  };
I need the sorted array in the following format
0, 
0.0, 
0.0.0,
0.0.1,
0.0.4,
0.1,
1,
2,
3,
14,
14.0
```

Plz help....

Comment: Those aren't valid string literals. I assume you mean `{ "0", "1", etc... }`?

Comment: Can these number be > 10, and in that case are the lower ones zero-padded?

Comment: Plz check.. I modified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have changed requirements, your own comparator is the right solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyCmp implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String[] parts1 = o1.split("\\.");
        String[] parts2 = o2.split("\\.");
        int max = Math.max(parts1.length, parts2.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (i < parts1.length && i < parts2.length) {
                Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[i]);
                Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(parts2[i]);
                if (i1 == i2)
                    continue;
                return i1.compareTo(i2);
            }
            if (i < parts1.length) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (i < parts2.length) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] menuIndex = { "0",
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "0.0",
                "0.0.1",
                "0.0.0",
                "0.0.4",
                "14",
                "14.0",
                "0.1" };
        Arrays.sort(menuIndex, new MyCmp());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(menuIndex));
    }

}
```

Comment: Plz check.. I modified the question

Answer (score 1):

Create your own comparator and sort the array using it.

Comment: It is too complex, for him it is enough standard solution with Arrays.sort()

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays.sort method for sorting..below is the code.

```
  String [] menuIndex= { "0","1","2","3","0.0","0.0.1","0.0.0","0.0.4","4","4.0","0.1"};
            Arrays.sort(menuIndex);
            for(String str:menuIndex){
                System.out.println(str);
            }
```